# Periodicity for overnight stock data

Tags: r, quantmod

I frequently use to.daily to convert 1 min OHLC data to a daily format but am trying to find a way to do the same with overnight data. I was hoping to see the option to specify what time a "day" starts and ends but didn't see that.

Overnight session being 18:00 to 09:30.

Does anyone have a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use time-of-day subsetting with `which.i = TRUE` to find all of the observations you don't want. Then subset the original data with the negative of the result, so all the non-overnight observations will be dropped.

```
# assume data are in a xts object named 'x'
DayObs <- x["T09:30/T18:30", which.i = TRUE]
Overnight <- x[-DayObs,]
```

You might need to change the start and end times in the time-of-day subset call.

---

If you already have your data subset so that it only includes the overnight session, you can aggregate to "daily" using `period.apply()` and custom endpoints. Assuming your data are in an object named `x`:

```
ep <- c(0, which(diff(.indexhour(x) > 9 & .indexmin(x) > 30) == 1))
makeOHLC <- function(x) {
  op <- as.numeric(first(x))
  cl <- as.numeric(last(x))
  c(Open = op, High = max(x), Low = min(x), Close = cl)
}
period.apply(x, ep, makeOHLC)
```

Comment: Sorry if I am understanding wrong but that will just give me a subset of my data, correct? I have the data for the overnight session in a XTS already, in 1 min OHLC format. What I want to do is convert that to daily data but using to.daily assumes a "day" is 00:00 to 23:59 where I need a "day" to be 18:00 to 09:29 the following day.

Comment: “Fake” your timezone to a timezone 6 hours ahead so that it starts at midnight  and then use `to.daily`.

Comment: Thanks hvollmeier. While not the prettiest of solutions, that will def work until I get around to writing a function as there doesn't seem to be a way to do this easily.   If you add your answer I will mark it as correct and upvote. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich No worries at all. Thanks very much for following up!